# Equivalence of continuous functions

Tags: general-topology, continuity

Consider two topological spaces, $X$ and $Y$, and two continuous functions $f$ and $g$. By definition, given an open set $S$ in $Y$, the pre-image of $S$ under $f$ (or $g$) is an open set of $X$.

Let us say that $f$ and $g$ are equivalent iff given any open set $S$ in $Y$, the pre-image of $S$ under $f$ is the same as the pre-image of $S$ under $g$.

Is there a name for this kind of equivalence? Is it a useful concept in general topology?

Comment: Out of curiosity, do you have an example of two different yet equivalent functions?

Comment: If Y is Hausdorff, then we must have $f=g$ - since if $f(x) \ne f(y)$, then we can find $U, V$ open with $y \not\in f^{-1}(x)$

Comment: If $Y$ is $T_0$ (e.g., Hausdorff), then any $y\in Y$ is the intersection of all the open neighborhoods $U$ containing it. Hence any two equivalent $f,g$ have $\{f^{-1}(y)\} = \bigcap_U f^{-1}(U) = \bigcap_U g^{-1}(U) = \{g^{-1}(y)\}$, forcing $f = g$.

Comment: On the other hand, if $Y$ has the trivial topology (i.e, only $\varnothing$ and $Y$ are open in $Y$), then any two functions $f, g$ are equivalent.

Comment: @anomaly: $T_0$ isn’t sufficient to make the singleton of each point the intersection of all open nbhds of that point: look at $\Bbb N$ with the topology $\{\Bbb N\}\cup\{U_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$, where $U_n=\{k\in\Bbb N:k<n\}$. You need $Y$ to be $T_1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Oops, yes, for some reason I thought mutually non-contained neighborhoods was $T_0$ rather than $T_1$.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be considering the equivalence described by germs of functions: [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germ_(mathematics)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germ_%28mathematics%29)

Comment: That doesn't seem related? Germ is a local property (agreement of two functions in a neighbourhood) whereas this is conceptually almost the opposite: the same preimage sets regardless of how the functions behave within those sets.